# Authorazation with JWT Token - How to get Authorized Automatically

Tags: c#, jwt, authorization, token

I'm having a problem getting a user to be authorized.

I'm making a web Api and in the controller where the login method is, it creates a token (JWT Token / Bearer Token), but I don't know how to put the user who logged in automatically authorized.

"Manually" and by swagger I had the following that was after login I had the token and in one button (AddSwaggerGen(options => { options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme) put the word bearer + ' ' + token and I was already authorized but at the moment I'm trying to replace the swagger with normal html + js. (I call methods by fetch) and when pressing the login button he has to do the authentication and authorization soon.

I send the code I have from my project:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Login(LoginModel request)
        {
          //Here i have code who checks if is a valid user

            string token = CreateToken(user); //creates a token giving roles, keys, creds, 
                                                put in a var token and do a jwtsecurity

            var refreshToken = GenerateRefreshToken(); //this is useful for refreshTokens 
            
            //check if string token is valid
            if (!ValidateToken(token))
            {
                return BadRequest("Check if is a valid token!");
            }
            
            //this method is just to put the refresh token with the user
            SetRefreshToken(refreshToken);

            //here i just have code who updates the database refresh token

            //THE REAL PROBLEM (this is not working)
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
                AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }
            
            // Also I try do just this line but it gives me a error in the httpClient not 
            being recognize
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
            AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            return Ok(token);
        }
```

Does anyone know how to replace the code I have to correctly do the automatic authorization?

Any common sense answer is always welcome and sorry if my english is not the best

Comment: The client you are declaring goes out of scope and is disposed as soon as it leaves the `using` statement. Make your `HttpClient` on a global scope and set the header, or use a global variable to store your token and then add it to the header of each `HttpClient` instance when you are ready to make a call to an endpoint.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson I still have the errors, I don't know if the problem is mine or X. Can you give a illustrative example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that you are confusing the concepts of authentication and authorization, as explained by the ASP.NET Core documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> Authentication is the process of determining a user's identity. Authorization is the process of determining whether a user has access to a resource.

So that means both processes can't be done together.

As you can see on this [JWT Auth flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLY1R.png), you have to first authenticate the user, so your API can issue a JWT for this user and send it back to your API's consumer/client application.

Your consumer/client application is now responsible to store the issued JWT token (e.g. local storage for a web app) and attach it to the HTTP Authorization header of every request that it needs to be authorized for the user, your API is only responsible to verify the JWT token.

To do so with the `[Authorize]` attribute you have to add the following configuration on your startup file.

```cs
// Startup.cs

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // JWT validation configuration
     services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
          var symmetricKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(symmetricKeyValue));

          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
                IssuerSigningKey = symmetricKey,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                ValidIssuer = issuerValue,
                ValidAudience = audienceValue,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
          };
      });

      // Enables [Authorize] attribute
      services.AddAuthorization();

      // API controllers or your endpoint configuration
      services.AddControllers();
}
```

Note: All the values on `services.AddAuthentication()` can be configured accordingly to your needs.

Comment: The 2 lasts links are useful if you want to start to understand / create user applications but my problem is how to do authorization when you do a login call. For example in the postman, you ctrl + c the token to put in box of the bearer token and I don´t want go to that way, do you understand? Also unfortunately the asp.net.core Identity don´t have the web api example so its a big F for me :c

Comment: Ok, by looking at your code and with your answer, do you mean how does a client application attach the JWT token to the HTTP Authorization header after login or for subsequent requests? If that is not the case, what resource are you trying to authorize exactly?

Comment: Yep, that's my problem, in the client server when it does the login I want to that authorization, attaching the JWT token to the HTTP so when it calls other methods and if that methods have [Authorize], is authorized to run the methods

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly to the clarification.